# What syntax to query a custom work item field

Tags: tfs, field, workitem

I am using the Event Subscription Tool, which sits on top of the bissubscribe.exe tool to create some custom alerts. I need to query against some custom work item fields, but I'm not sure how to reference them in the code.

Here is how you reference a system field (this works):

```
CoreFields/StringFields/Field[ReferenceName='System.AssignedTo']/NewValue" = 
          'Daniel, Jim'
```

Here is how I'm attempting to reference a custom field (this does not work):

```
"CoreFields/StringFields/Field[ReferenceName='ProductBacklogItem.CustomField.1']/NewValue" 
          = '400'
```

Am I referencing the custom field wrong? I can find no documentation how to reference it. I am wondering if the custom fields live under "CoreFields..." -- doesn't seem like they would, but I don't know where they would be.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. You cannot access the custom fields through "CoreFields" in an event. You may only access a custom field that has changed, and you must access it like this:

```
"ChangedFields/StringFields/Field[ReferenceName='ProductBacklogItem.CustomField.1']/NewValue" 
      = '400'
```